# SharePoint 2010 - how to make multi-column a unique value

Tags: sharepoint

i'm implementing a sand box solution where is should have more than one column a unique key, i have to use the item adding event receiver but how to get the current adding item field values to know if this item is occurred within the list.

thanks

Comment: 1- create UniqueID column and make it unique.
2- create an event receiver as follows: 
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            string Name = properties.AfterProperties["Name"].ToString();
            string Title = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
            StringBuilder StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(Name);
            StringBuilder.Append("-");
            StringBuilder.Append(Title);
            properties.AfterProperties["UniqueID0"] = StringBuilder.ToString();
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
        }

Comment: Why the downvote? They asked a valid question and got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create UniqueID column and make it unique.
2. Create an event receiver as follows:

   ```
   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       string Name = properties.AfterProperties["Name"].ToString();
       string Title = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
       StringBuilder StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(Name);
       StringBuilder.Append("-");
       StringBuilder.Append(Title);
       properties.AfterProperties["UniqueID0"] = StringBuilder.ToString();
       base.ItemAdding(properties);
   }
   ```